# Почему jQuery использует id как атрибут для querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как известно, `jQuery.fn.find` по возможности пытается скормить селектор браузерному `querySelectorAll`.

При этом есть вариант, когда для некоторого элемента генерируется id, после чего браузеру достаётся селектор, в начало которого добавилась преверка на этот id.

Зачем вообще нужен этот фокус разобрался. Селектор ставится в соответствие не внутри элемента, а вообще в документе. Просто фильтруется поддерево.

Вопрос зачем делается выборка по *атрибуту* вместо *id*.
Т. е. почему `nid = "[id='" + nid + "'] ";`, а не `nid = "#" + nid + " ";`?

Более полный контекст для двух версий приведён далее:

#### 1.8.1

```
// qSA works strangely on Element-rooted queries
// We can work around this by specifying an extra ID on the root
// and working up from there (Thanks to Andrew Dupont for the technique)
// IE 8 doesn't work on object elements
} else if ( context.nodeType === 1 && context.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== "object" ) {
    var groups, i, len,
        old = context.getAttribute("id"),
        nid = old || expando,
        newContext = rsibling.test( selector ) && context.parentNode || context;

    if ( old ) {
        nid = nid.replace( rescape, "\\$&" );
    } else {
        context.setAttribute( "id", nid );
    }

    groups = tokenize(selector, context, xml);
    // Trailing space is unnecessary
    // There is always a context check
    nid = "[id='" + nid + "']";
    for ( i = 0, len = groups.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        groups[i] = nid + groups[i].selector;
    }
    try {
        push.apply( results, slice.call( newContext.querySelectorAll(
            groups.join(",")
        ), 0 ) );
        return results;
    } catch(qsaError) {
    } finally {
        if ( !old ) {
            context.removeAttribute("id");
        }
    }
}
```

#### 1.11.3

```
// qSA works strangely on Element-rooted queries
// We can work around this by specifying an extra ID on the root
// and working up from there (Thanks to Andrew Dupont for the technique)
// IE 8 doesn't work on object elements
if ( nodeType === 1 && context.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== "object" ) {
    groups = tokenize( selector );

    if ( (old = context.getAttribute("id")) ) {
        nid = old.replace( rescape, "\\$&" );
    } else {
        context.setAttribute( "id", nid );
    }
    nid = "[id='" + nid + "'] ";

    i = groups.length;
    while ( i-- ) {
        groups[i] = nid + toSelector( groups[i] );
    }
    newContext = rsibling.test( selector ) && testContext( context.parentNode ) || context;
    newSelector = groups.join(",");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Коротко о проблеме:

```
<div>
    <p id="foo">
        <span></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
console.log( foo.querySelectorAll('div span').length ); // 1
```

Проблема *querySelectorAll* в том, что сначала он вытащит все что подходит под селектор `div span` начиная с корня документа, а потом отфильтрует полученный результат на вхождение в элемент-контекст (`foo`) - т.е. селектор `div span` найдет один `span` и да - этот `span` находится внутри `#foo`.

Трюк с аттрибутами используется как раз для того, чтобы исключить элемент контекста и начинать запрос сразу с корня документа, избегая такой странной выборки. Небольшое пояснение кода:

```
if ( (old = context.getAttribute("id")) ) {
    nid = old.replace( rescape, "\\$&" );
} else {
    context.setAttribute( "id", nid );
}
```

Если у элемента-контекста есть *id*, то используем его, а иначе добавляем ему id с уникальным только что созданным хешем.

```
nid = "[id='" + nid + "'] ";
```

Преобразуем в селектор аттрибута, благодаря операции выше мы уверены, что у элемента-контекста всегда будет *id* - либо уникальный либо сгенерированный.

```
i = groups.length;
while ( i-- ) {
    groups[i] = nid + toSelector( groups[i] );
}
```

Группы - это если селекторов несколько (перечислены через запятую). Здесь в начало каждой группы добавляется селектор аттрибута. Если брать оригинальный пример с запросом `foo.querySelectorAll('div span')`, то группа в данном случае это `div span`, а после добавления аттрибута получится `[id="foo"] div span`. Пре передаче этого нового селектора в *querySelectorAll* запрос будет выполнен уже в рамках элемента-контекста не смотря ни на что.

Используются аттрибуты `[id="foo"]` вместо `#foo`, т.к. идентификатор [по спецификации](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name) может сожержать спецсимволы, которые очень сложно эскейпить самостоятельно, и в команде было принято решение скинуть парсинг идентификатора на браузер.

Источники:

- [John Resig - Thoughts on querySelectorAll](http://ejohn.org/blog/thoughts-on-queryselectorall/)
- [jquery/sizzle - Replace ID-attribute selectors with ID-selectors where possible #354](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/issues/354)
- [jquery/sizzle - Bug #7533. Fix for Element-rooted queries where ID contains CSS3 selector meta characters](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/pull/42)
- [jquery/sizzle - Bug #7533. Fix for IDs which contain CSS3 selector meta characters #37](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/pull/37)

Comment: Я это понял. Но почему надо `[id="foo"] div span`, если можно `#foo div span`? Зачем использовать именно атрибут вместо id?

Comment: Да, со ссылками лучше. Т. е. эта штуковина на случай, если id уже есть и он не является корректым для id'шного селектора? В какой версии они это изменение внесли?

Comment: Интересно, я пока тоже в поисках. [Вот есть занимательная переписка](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapi/2008Apr/0251.html) по этому поводу (Next message под сообщением)

Comment: По твоей второй ссылке тема закрыта и указана ссылка на [коммит](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/commit/1a8958f6bc25ffb1ff2a1306ffd28d0539f93f84). Кстати, он сделан 2 дня назад :) Вот исправление: `nidselect = ridentifier.test( nid ) ? "#" + nid : "[id='" + nid + "']";` - так что это для случая, когда в разметки чудо вроде `<div id="some.id">`, `<div id="smth[10]">` и других подобных ситуаций.

Comment: Дополни ответ, я его приму :)

Comment: И правда для эскейпа, до меня не дошло сразу. [Вот нарыл даже PR](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/pull/42), в котором было добавлено. Спасибо за интересный вопрос, было познавательно)

Comment: Вообще-то браузеры безо всякой спецификации едят любые символы в id :) А спецификация не та, [вот новая](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute) - в ней только про необходимость отсутствия пробельных символов говорится, но браузеры и их едет.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: Видимо я снова не в ту сторону ушел. В [ПР #37](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/pull/37) говорится, что это позволит свалить парсинг id на браузер вместо ручного парсинга всех возможных вариантов

Comment: Ага. Кстати, коммит был не 2 дня, а месяц назад - куда-то не туда посмотрел первый раз.