# Многократно запрашивается поиск по DOM'у одних и тех же элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery, оптимизация, dom

Есть проблемы с производительностью подписки на всплытие событий через jQuery. IE9 и IE11 указывают, что при клике 80% времени тратится на выполнение `querySelectorAll`. Анализ привёл в функцию `$.event.dispatch` (jQuery 1.8.1, в более новой версии (1.11.3) эта функциональность вынесена в `$.event.handlers`), которая содержит такой код:

```
for ( cur = event.target; cur != this; cur = cur.parentNode || this ) {

  // Don't process clicks (ONLY) on disabled elements (#6911, #8165, #11382, #11764)
  if ( cur.disabled !== true || event.type !== "click" ) {
    selMatch = {};
    matches = [];
    for ( i = 0; i < delegateCount; i++ ) {
      handleObj = handlers[ i ];
      sel = handleObj.selector;

      if ( selMatch[ sel ] === undefined ) {
        selMatch[ sel ] = jQuery( sel, this ).index( cur ) >= 0;
      }
      if ( selMatch[ sel ] ) {
        matches.push( handleObj );
      }
    }
    if ( matches.length ) {
      handlerQueue.push({ elem: cur, matches: matches });
    }
  }
}
```

Обращаю внимание на следующие строки:

```
// Для каждого элемента от кликнутого наверх
for ( cur = event.target; cur != this; cur = cur.parentNode || this ) {
    // Обнуляем кэш результатов поиска
    selMatch = {};

    // Для каждого из подписчиков
    for ( i = 0; i < delegateCount; i++ ) {
      // Берем селектор очередного подписчика
      sel = handleObj.selector;

      // Если такого селектора нет в кеше
      if ( selMatch[ sel ] === undefined ) {
        // Выполняем поиск всего соответствующего селектору
        // И запоминаем, есть ли просматриваемый внешним циклом элемент среди найденного
        selMatch[ sel ] = jQuery( sel, this ).index( cur ) >= 0;
```

Поскольку подписка сделана на всплытие до `body`, каждый такой поиск вытаскивает из всего документа все элементы, соответствующие селектору. Причём, этот одинаковый список запрашивается столько раз, сколько родительских элементов имеет кликнутый.

Насколько я понимаю, внешний цикл нужен для правильной последовательности вызова обработчиков в порядке всплытия события. Есть кэш, который работает в пределах одного уровня вложенности и помогает только в случае многократной подписки на один и тот же селектор.

Собственно вопрос: почему кэш реализован именно так? Почему бы не сохранять в кэше найденный набор, а в последующий if перенести проверку вместе с `index`?

---

Но это не всё. Я посмотрел реализацию в актуальной версии 1.11.3. В ней по-прежнему делается такое же количество запросов, но строка изменяется.

Вот что было в 1.8.1:

```
selMatch[ sel ] = jQuery( sel, this ).index( cur ) >= 0;
```

и вот что стало в 1.11.3:

```
matches[ sel ] = handleObj.needsContext ?
jQuery( sel, this ).index( cur ) >= 0 :
jQuery.find( sel, this, null, [ cur ] ).length;
```

Здесь уже такая модификация кэширования кажется сомнительной.

---

Итак, вопросы:

1. По какой причине код мог быть написан именно таким неоптимальным способом.
2. Как лучше поступить, чтобы избежать проблем с производительностью?

---

Следующий сниппет показывает проблему множественных вызовов поиска:

Надо открыть консоль браузера и нажать на `Click me to get a lot of searches!`.
В консоль будет **21 раз** выведено

```
qsa [id='sizcache041783330822363496'] section .smth
gbc smth-other
```

По поводу куска `[id='sizcache041783330822363496']` есть [родственный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/465128/178988) - эта форма убирает необходимость экранирования. Недавно в Sizzle [было внесено изменение по этому поводу](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/commit/1a8958f6bc25ffb1ff2a1306ffd28d0539f93f84), но даже актуальная версия jQuery его не содержит.

```js
$(function () {
  $("body")
  .on("click", "section .smth", function () { console.log("clicked", "section .smth") })
  .on("click", ".smth-other", function () { console.log("clicked", ".smth-other") });

  $("h1").text("Click me to get a lot of searches!");

  var qsa = Element.prototype.querySelectorAll, gbc = Element.prototype.getElementsByClassName;
  Element.prototype.querySelectorAll = function(s) { console.log('qsa', s); return qsa.apply(this, arguments) };
  Element.prototype.getElementsByClassName = function(s) { console.log('gbc', s); return gbc.apply(this, arguments) };
});
```

```css
body { counter-reset: lev 1; }
div { counter-increment: lev; }
h1, h2 { cursor: pointer; }
h1:hover, h2:hover { background: silver; }
h1:after { content: " (" counter(lev) ")"; }
```

```html
<div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><h1>
  Loading...
</h1></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>

<section>
  <h2 class="smth">I'm smth and i'm waiting for a click</h2>
</section>

<section>
  <h2 class="smth-other">I'm smth other and i'm waiting for a click</h2>
</section>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.js"></script>
```

---

В следующий сниппет помещён код функции dispatch из jQuery 1.8.1 (сниппет нужен для получения сворачиваемого спойлера, пытаться его запускать бесполезно):

```js
dispatch: function( event ) {

  // Make a writable jQuery.Event from the native event object
  event = jQuery.event.fix( event || window.event );

  var i, j, cur, ret, selMatch, matched, matches, handleObj, sel, related,
    handlers = ( (jQuery._data( this, "events" ) || {} )[ event.type ] || []),
    delegateCount = handlers.delegateCount,
    args = [].slice.call( arguments ),
    run_all = !event.exclusive && !event.namespace,
    special = jQuery.event.special[ event.type ] || {},
    handlerQueue = [];

  // Use the fix-ed jQuery.Event rather than the (read-only) native event
  args[0] = event;
  event.delegateTarget = this;

  // Call the preDispatch hook for the mapped type, and let it bail if desired
  if ( special.preDispatch && special.preDispatch.call( this, event ) === false ) {
    return;
  }

  // Determine handlers that should run if there are delegated events
  // Avoid non-left-click bubbling in Firefox (#3861)
  if ( delegateCount && !(event.button && event.type === "click") ) {

    for ( cur = event.target; cur != this; cur = cur.parentNode || this ) {

      // Don't process clicks (ONLY) on disabled elements (#6911, #8165, #11382, #11764)
      if ( cur.disabled !== true || event.type !== "click" ) {
        selMatch = {};
        matches = [];
        for ( i = 0; i < delegateCount; i++ ) {
          handleObj = handlers[ i ];
          sel = handleObj.selector;

          if ( selMatch[ sel ] === undefined ) {
            selMatch[ sel ] = jQuery( sel, this ).index( cur ) >= 0;
          }
          if ( selMatch[ sel ] ) {
            matches.push( handleObj );
          }
        }
        if ( matches.length ) {
          handlerQueue.push({ elem: cur, matches: matches });
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Add the remaining (directly-bound) handlers
  if ( handlers.length > delegateCount ) {
    handlerQueue.push({ elem: this, matches: handlers.slice( delegateCount ) });
  }

  // Run delegates first; they may want to stop propagation beneath us
  for ( i = 0; i < handlerQueue.length && !event.isPropagationStopped(); i++ ) {
    matched = handlerQueue[ i ];
    event.currentTarget = matched.elem;

    for ( j = 0; j < matched.matches.length && !event.isImmediatePropagationStopped(); j++ ) {
      handleObj = matched.matches[ j ];

      // Triggered event must either 1) be non-exclusive and have no namespace, or
      // 2) have namespace(s) a subset or equal to those in the bound event (both can have no namespace).
      if ( run_all || (!event.namespace && !handleObj.namespace) || event.namespace_re && event.namespace_re.test( handleObj.namespace ) ) {

        event.data = handleObj.data;
        event.handleObj = handleObj;

        ret = ( (jQuery.event.special[ handleObj.origType ] || {}).handle || handleObj.handler )
            .apply( matched.elem, args );

        if ( ret !== undefined ) {
          event.result = ret;
          if ( ret === false ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Call the postDispatch hook for the mapped type
  if ( special.postDispatch ) {
    special.postDispatch.call( this, event );
  }

  return event.result;
},
```

PS: [Этот же вопрос на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34402369/4928642)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34402369/4928642

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перенёс строку с сохранением кэша выше:

```
if ( delegateCount && !(event.button && event.type === "click") ) {
    selMatch = {};
```

И вынес `index` из кэширования в проверку:

```
if ( selMatch[ sel ] === undefined ) {
    selMatch[ sel ] = jQuery( sel, this );
}
if ( selMatch[ sel ].index( cur ) >= 0 ) {
    matches.push( handleObj );
}
```