# Как сделать многоуровневое вертикальное меню accordion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Хочу получить многоуровневое меню аккордеон:
оформление не важно, главное работающий сценарий jQuery.
Использую этот код:

```
jQuery(function($){
$('.multi-accordion li > a').on('click', function (event) {
    var $this = $(this), $next = $this.next();
    if ($next.length) {
    $next.slideToggle().parent().siblings().children('ul').filter(':visible').slideToggle();
    event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

});

Html разметка может меняться при добавлении новых категорий в админ-панели.

```
<div>
    <ul class="multi-accordion">
        <li><a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a.html">Category level 1 (a)</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a/category-level2a.html">Category level 2 (a)</a></li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a/category-level2a/category-level3a.html">Category level 3 (a)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a/category-level2a/category-level3b.html">Category level 3 (b)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a/category-level2a/category-level3c.html">Category level 3 (c)</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <li><a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a/category-level2b.html">Category level 2 (b)</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a/category-level2c.html">Category level 2 (c)</a></li>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1b.html">Category level 1 (b)</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1c.html">Category level 1 (c)</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Меню свёрнуто, но не активно.

Comment: а вы уверены что вам именно аккордеон нужен? больше на какое-нибудь меню похоже

Comment: Да, оно и было на сайте, только усложнилось дополнительными уровнями, сейчас ниже написал как это выглядит в аналогии с обычным index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '.multi-accordion li > a', function (event) {
    var $this = $(this), $next = $this.next();

    if ($next.length) {
    $next.slideToggle().parent().siblings().children('ul').filter(':visible').slideToggle();
    //$next.slideToggle().parent().siblings().find('ul').filter(':visible').slideToggle();
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Вариант с `children` запоминает развёрнутость внутри свёрнутого, а с `find` - нет.

Подписку лучше делать по классу, а не по составному селектору, [подробнее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/476703/178988).

https://jsfiddle.net/8efyLh93/5/

Чтобы скрывать вложенные, надо сделать так:

```
$(document).on('click', '.multi-accordion li > a', function (event) {
  var $this = $(this), $next = $this.next();

  if ($next.length) {
    if ($next.is(':visible')) {
      $next.slideToggle(function () {
        $next.find('ul').toggle(false);
      });
    } else {
      $next.slideToggle().parent().siblings().find('ul').filter(':visible').slideToggle();
    }

    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8efyLh93/8/

```js
$(document).on('click', '.multi-accordion li > a', function (event) {
 var $this = $(this), $next = $this.next();
  
 if ($next.length) {
   $next.slideToggle().parent().siblings().children('ul').filter(':visible').slideToggle();
    //$next.slideToggle().parent().siblings().find('ul').filter(':visible').slideToggle();
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  padding: 0;
}

a, a:link, a:visited {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .25em;
}

a:hover {
  background: silver;
}

a:only-child:link, a:only-child:visited {
  color: blue;
}

a:only-child:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background: transparent;
}

li ul {
  display: none;
  margin: 0 .25em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<base href="https://yandex.ru/search/" target="_blank">

<ul class="multi-accordion">
  <li>
    <a href="?text=one">One</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="?text=expandable">Expandable</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="?text=two">Two</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="?text=three">Three</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">More</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="?text=1-32">1 - 32</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="?text=1">1</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=2">2</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=4">4</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=8">8</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=16">16</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=32">32</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="?text=64-256">64 - 256</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="?text=64">64</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=128">128</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=256">256</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="?text=512-1024">512 - 1024</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="?text=512">512</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=1024">1024</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Other</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="?text=other-1-32">other-1 - 32</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="?text=other-1">other-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=other-2">other-2</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=other-4">other-4</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=other-8">other-8</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=other-16">other-16</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=other-32">other-32</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="?text=other-64-256">other-64 - 256</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="?text=other-64">other-64</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=other-128">other-128</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=other-256">other-256</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="?text=other-512-1024">other-512 - 1024</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="?text=other-512">other-512</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=other-1024">other-1024</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="?text=expandable">Expandable</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="?text=two">Two</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="?text=three">Three</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">More</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="?text=1-32">1 - 32</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="?text=1">1</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=2">2</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=4">4</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=8">8</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=16">16</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=32">32</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="?text=64-256">64 - 256</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="?text=64">64</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=128">128</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=256">256</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="?text=512-1024">512 - 1024</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="?text=512">512</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=1024">1024</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Other</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="?text=other-1-32">other-1 - 32</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="?text=other-1">other-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=other-2">other-2</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=other-4">other-4</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=other-8">other-8</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=other-16">other-16</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=other-32">other-32</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="?text=other-64-256">other-64 - 256</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="?text=other-64">other-64</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=other-128">other-128</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=other-256">other-256</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="?text=other-512-1024">other-512 - 1024</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="?text=other-512">other-512</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=other-1024">other-1024</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="?text=expandable">Expandable</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="?text=two">Two</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="?text=three">Three</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">More</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="?text=1-32">1 - 32</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="?text=1">1</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=2">2</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=4">4</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=8">8</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=16">16</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=32">32</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="?text=64-256">64 - 256</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="?text=64">64</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=128">128</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=256">256</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="?text=512-1024">512 - 1024</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="?text=512">512</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=1024">1024</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Other</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="?text=other-1-32">other-1 - 32</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="?text=other-1">other-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=other-2">other-2</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=other-4">other-4</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=other-8">other-8</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=other-16">other-16</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=other-32">other-32</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="?text=other-64-256">other-64 - 256</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="?text=other-64">other-64</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=other-128">other-128</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=other-256">other-256</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="?text=other-512-1024">other-512 - 1024</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="?text=other-512">other-512</a></li>
              <li><a href="?text=other-1024">other-1024</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Qwertiy, подключил скрипт, не работает почему-то. Что-то не так делаю. На сайте видно как я подставил. Функции в справочнике посмотрел, но в целом картину не понял...:-(

Comment: @SergeyEremin, подробнее?

Comment: Меню выводится списком как без скрипта. А на скрине сам [скрипт](http://imglink.ru/show-image.php?id=11d980cf80eca745320baaa85c4a57bb).

Comment: подключенные библиотеки `jquery 1.10.2` и `jquery-ui` (accordion)

Comment: @SergeyEremin, ты в css потерял `display:none`.

Comment: Прописал css, они закрылись, только работают как ссылки (не раскрываются), и продолжают ошибки сыпаться...:-(

Comment: @SergeyEremin, какие ещё ошибки?

Comment: [ссылка на скрин](http://imglink.ru/show-image.php?id=11d980cf80eca745320baaa85c4a57bb) В консоли пишет "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input".

Comment: тип кавычек смените , js такие не приемлет =(

Comment: @SergeyEremin, а где ещё `})`?

Comment: @redroid, что??

Comment: Судя по учебнику в jquery нет разницы между одинарными и двойными кавычками. Тут что-то другое. По отдельности все выражения посмотрел, но не могу понять почему от первых пунктов дальше не получается идти, будто нужна проверка на вложение.

Comment: @SergeyEremin, я уже сказал, что тут.

Comment: Сейчас всё как у меня в вопросе код. Не понимаю, надо ещё раз поставить `})`? Поставил в конце ещё раз, ничего не изменилось...:-(

Comment: @SergeyEremin, ну ты б хоть парность скобок считать научился...

Comment: Получается если две открывающие `{` то будет в конце две `});`? Объясните, пожалуйста, как надо и почему?

Comment: @SergeyEremin, прочитай наконец, что такое правильная скобочная последовательность.

Comment: Поправил, ошибки теперь нет. Но свёрнутые вкладки работают как ссылки, а первая должна открываться так как в ней вложение. В какую сторону копать?

Comment: @SergeyEremin, в сторону отладки скрипта. Ставишь брейкпоинт на первой строчке и смотришь, что там не так.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33720/discussion-between-sergey-eremin-and-qwertiy).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте посмотреть, возможно подойдет с модификациями: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/fainder/pen/AydHJ)

```js
$(function() {
 var Accordion = function(el, multiple) {
  this.el = el || {};
  this.multiple = multiple || false;

  // Variables privadas
  var links = this.el.find('.link');
  // Evento
  links.on('click', {el: this.el, multiple: this.multiple}, this.dropdown)
 }

 Accordion.prototype.dropdown = function(e) {
  var $el = e.data.el;
   $this = $(this),
   $next = $this.next();

  $next.slideToggle();
  $this.parent().toggleClass('open');

  if (!e.data.multiple) {
   $el.find('.submenu').not($next).slideUp().parent().removeClass('open');
  };
 } 

 var accordion = new Accordion($('#accordion'), false);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #2d2c41;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif, Verdana, Tahoma;
}

ul { list-style-type: none; }

a {
  color: #b63b4d;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/** =======================
 * Contenedor Principal
 ===========================*/


h1 {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

h1 a {
  color: #c12c42;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 30px auto 20px;
  background: #FFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.accordion .link {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 42px;
  color: #4D4D4D;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.accordion li:last-child .link { border-bottom: 0; }

.accordion li i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 12px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #595959;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.accordion li i.fa-chevron-down {
  right: 12px;
  left: auto;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.accordion li.open .link { color: #b63b4d; }

.accordion li.open i { color: #b63b4d; }

.accordion li.open i.fa-chevron-down {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

/**
 * Submenu
 -----------------------------*/


.submenu {
  display: none;
  background: #444359;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.submenu li { border-bottom: 1px solid #4b4a5e; }

.submenu a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  padding: 12px;
  padding-left: 42px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

.submenu a:hover {
  background: #b63b4d;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<h1>Smooth Accordion Dropdown Menu Demo</h1>
<!-- Contenedor -->
<ul id="accordion" class="accordion">
  <li>
    <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-database"></i>Web Design<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-code"></i>Coding<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Javascript</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ruby</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i>Devices<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Tablet</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Desktop</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>Global<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Yahoo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: К сожалению не подходит, привязка по классам, а не ul, и уровня всего два, очень сложно будет его изменить на 3 уровня в силу отсутствия знаний...:-(

Comment: @SergeyEremin, [тут](http://pcvector.net/scripts/menu_and_navigation/172-mnogourovnevoe-menyu-tipa-akkordeon.html) не смотрели?)


Немного другая реализация есть еще и [тут](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=2&id=2479)

Comment: Спасибо, вам за помощь!!! Самое сложное это найти и применить подходящий аккордеон к моему коду. Хоть я и написал ниже дерево как оно выглядит. Там видимо есть то, чего понять не могу, чтобы наложить разметку аккордеона на мой код. Сейчас добавлю его в вопрос.

Comment: @SergeyEremin, вижу все же получилось. Не раскрываться могло по той причине, что не подключен или подключен старый jquery, либо неверно прописаны css

Comment: Вчера весь день мучился изменений не было, сегодня зашел часть работает. Но не всё, получается, что всё равно придётся искать и дорабатывать структуру и jquery код... Скажите, пожалуйста, а если я вместо библиотеки jquery 1.10.2 (которая была в шаблоне) установлю 1.11.3 ничего не испортится?

Answer (score 0):

Можно реализовать примерно так:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class="submenu-opener">Category (level 1)</a>
        <ul style="display: none;">
            <li>
                <a class="submenu-opener">Subcategory (level 2)</a>
                <ul style="display: none;">
                    <li>
                        <a>Subcategory</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>Subcategory</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>Subcategory</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

И javascript (с использованием библиотеки jQuery)

```
$('.submenu-opener').on('click', function(){
    $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Leoxr4an/1/

Comment: К сожалению не работает...:-( Тут вся сложность нацепить то, что работает на обычном index.hml на код, что у меня выше...

Answer (score 0):

Вот ваш вариант думаю

```
$("ul").hide().eq(0).show();
$("a").on("click", function() {
  $(this).parent().children('ul').stop().slideToggle();
});
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/9zpo2evd/1/

Comment: А куда эту часть вставить скажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function () { /*сюда код , то что есть у вас тут удалите*/ });`

Comment: Не работает, тут не хватает строки присвоения аккордеона по id. И её добавление тоже не помогает. Только как на коде выше работают только клики, без ссылок.

Comment: А зачем он там , это тупо универсальный код который будет работать с любой конструкцией `<ul><li><a>`

Comment: Но в этом случае он не работает...:-( Предполагаю, что так как меню многоуровневое и динамическое, то тут нужно скрипту указать, что делать и в каком случае. на данный момент работает только эта функция `jQuery(function($){
$('#cssmenu li.has-sub > a').on('click', function(){`

Comment: не , это все не играет роли . Вы переходили по ссылке которую я дал ? там как раз ваше меню , и все работает , тут вариант только ели у вас на самой странице есть какойто код который уже работает с этим меню и навешывает на него свои обработчики , или на странице ошибки которые завершают работу js . Откройте консоль и посмотрите .

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33648/discussion-between-sergey-eremin-and-redroid).