# Помогите с аккордионом

Tags: javascript

У меня есть код который открывает меню. И их можно открыть все сразу. Как сделать, когда нажимаешь на другое меню чтобы предыдущее закрывалось?

```js
$('.block-my_ad').click(function(){
  $(this).find('ul').slideToggle(300);
});
```

```html
<div class="block-my_ad">
 <p class="my_ad-title" ><strong>'.$row["title"].'</strong></p>
 <p class="my_ad-datetime" >'.$row["datatime"].'</p>
  
  
 <ul>
 <div class="block-images-my_ad">
    <img src="' . $img_path . '" width="' . $width . '" height="' . $height . '">
  </div>
 <li><strong>Категория</strong> - '.$row["category"].'</li>
 <li><strong>Цель</strong> - '. (!empty($row["x"]) ? $row["x"] : (!empty($row["y"]) ? $row["y"] : $row["t"])) . '</li>
 <li><strong>Город</strong> - '.$row["gorod"].'</li>
 <li><strong>Телефон</strong> - '.$row["phone"].'</li>
 <li><strong>Описание</strong> - '.$row["descriptions"].'</li>
 <p class="my_ad-links" ><a class="delete" rel="my_ad.php?id='.$row["products_id"].'&action=delete" >Удалить</a></p>
 </ul>
  </div>
 ';
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478860/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%83%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e-accordion посмотрите.

Comment: Я пытался что то подобное сделать, не получается:(

Comment: Вы что то путаете, это не дубликат вопроса! И то что вы показываете я такой вопрос вообще не задавал

Comment: @Евгений "дубликат" не означает, что этот вопрос именно вы задавали. Речь о том, что задавался аналогичный вопрос и ответы на тот вопрос подходят и для вашего вопроса.

Comment: Прошу прощения. Понял спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте к элементам ul, которые планируете использовать, атрибут *data-accordion-item-id='**id**'* , где **id** должно быть уникальным.

Например

```
<ul data-accordion-item-id="'.$row["products_id"].'"></ul>
```

Тогда вашу задачу можно будет решить следующим способом

```
$('.block-my_ad').click(function(){
   var current = $(this).find('ul')
   current.slideToggle(300);
   if (!opened_id) {
      opened_id = current.data('accordion-item-id');
   } else if (current.data('accordion-item-id') == opened_id) {
      opened_id = null;
   } else {
      $('*[data-accordion-item-id="' + opened_id + '"]').slideToggle(300);
      opened_id = current.data('accordion-item-id');
   }
});
```

Comment: ваш код работает, но когда я открываю другой блок, первый остается открытым также, а мне надо чтобы он закрывался:(

Comment: Я видать не верно вас понял. У вас в примере только один блок. Приведите пример где несколько блоков. Я кажется понял что вы имеете в виду, но уточнение будет не лишним.

Comment: Блок появляется когда человек подает объявления, щяс скину скрины. на скрине показа 4 объявления из них я 3 открыл а один закрыт. Скрипт наглядно показывает что не закрывает предыдущие объявления

Comment: Извините, была ошибка, поправил

Comment: Ой спасибо тебе большое) да вот оно что я хотел спасибо))

Comment: А можно ли как то сделать, чтобы нажать на одно и тоже объявление, чтобы оно закрылось просто, о то нажимаю на одно и тоже, оно закрывается и сразу же открывается:)

Comment: if(opened != $(this).find('ul'))  - эта проверка должна отвечать за то что бы вкладка не открывалась повторно. Попробуйте подебажить.

Comment: Что то я не смог все таки подебажить((

Comment: Обновил ответ, попробуйте сейчас.

Comment: Странно как то, это весь скрипт, там ul только 1. Не работает( Ваш предыдущий код больше по нраву, но он почему-то не закрывает блок при повторном нажатии

Comment: это php? Ваш код - это шаблон. На самом деле у вас на странице будет много элементов ul

Comment: В качестве id можете использовать products_id. Добавил пример, только вероятно нужно будет экранировать кавычки.

Comment: да я так и сделал, он щяс закрывается при повторном нажатии, но автоматически не закрывается при нажатии на другой блок:(

Comment: попробуйте добавить ковычки в селектор: $('*[data-accordion-item-id="' + opened_id + '"]').slideToggle(300);

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44995/discussion-between--and-alexey-prokopenko).